# Using %s properly (Python)

Tags: python

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect('localhost','root','12345','cba')
myCursor = conn.cursor()
tn = str(input("Enter table name : "))
myCursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE %s (rollno int primary key auto_increment,name varchar(20),age varchar(50))"""%(tn,))
name = str(input("Enter name :"))
age = str(input("Enter age :"))
myCursor.execute("""insert into %s (name,age) values(%s,%s) """%(tn,)),(name , age)
print("Table name %s created"%(tn,))
```

i am getting error in line

```
myCursor.execute("""insert into %s (name,age) values(%s,%s)"""%(tn,name,age))
```

i tried

```
myCursor.execute("""insert into %s (name,age) values(%s,%s) """%(tn,)),(name,age)
```

please help me i am stil learning

Comment: You should note that the `%` construct is now deprecated in Python. You should learn the `format()` method of strings instead, though there are some other up-to-date ways as well.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please read on SQL injection

Comment: @RoryDaulton In this case here `format` is just as bad as `%`. Instead of risking SQL injection by manually formatting values into queries, you should let the DB engine handle that.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I was concentrating on just one aspect of the OP's code, the one clear in his question title. As you point out, other issues exist, but that does not contradict my comment.

Comment: The format isnot correct for mysql syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're mixing python's formatting method and pymsql's statement formatting. `execute` accepts args tuple for input values.
2. `execute` method doesn't allow inserting table's name. As as I understand documentation It has no any method for such operation http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/index.html

So, you may use

```
sql = """insert into `{}` (name,age) values(%s,%s) """.format(tn)
myCursor.execute(sql ,(name , age))
```

**Edit**
But, this code is not perfect in the light of security. The first statement accepts any **bad** table name and inserts into sql statement. Please read about **SQL injection**. You should do some user input sanitation before inserting values into SQL statements directly.

`execute` statement should be OK as long as it takes care of escaping values.

Comment: @BivekKumarJaiswal I've added some notes about security. Please pay attention